# Laravel Projected is running with ip (http://127.0.0.1:8000/login) but not by folder path (http://localhost/laravel/login)

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a new laravel project, I am facing few problems, related to the project URL and PHP artisan serve command?

1. My project URL is http://localhost/laravel/login, which is showing site error page, the same is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/login. When i am using PHP artisan serve. Why is it so?
2. When i am running php artisan serve, my code is running at url http://127.0.0.1:8000/login. Question is why and how to set the folder url working for the same.
3. to run this URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/login, I have to always run the PHP artisan serve command, if not it shows page not found error.

I am new to laravel, So plz help me with above mentioned issue.

Comment: In order to serve your site you run `php artisan serve` - that's just how Laravel works. Without running that there will be no server running, and that's why you'd get an error when trying to access the site. Where are you getting http://localhost/laravel/login from?

Comment: @121c So you mean i have to run php artisan serve command each time i have to access the code.
But this is not issue with my other project. i can access it from my folder path, with out any issue. This is what i want to do. As mentioned in point 1.

Comment: Each time you want to run the code on your computer, yes.You run the server and then the client (browser) makes requests to that server. Once the server receives a request, it generates a response (e.g. maybe the response contains HTML/CSS files or JSON) and sends that back to the client.

Comment: @121c- so what changes i have to made to access it via folder path. http://localhost/laravel/login, not with http://127.0.0.1:8000/login.

Comment: You'd need to serve it off of port 80 and not port 8000, and change the routes file (`routes/web.php`) to handle requests to `/laravel/login`, but I don't think that's a good idea. Local development using `localhost:8000` is totally fine and very common. Also, localhost and 127.0.0.1 are the same thing (generally)

Comment: i have multiple projects to work on, due to which i prefer using the folder name to access them directly... My other projects are working fine , but dn't know what is the issue in this. So plz suggest me what changes i have to do in routes/web.php

Answer (score 0):

If everything is ok and you don't have any wrong with your PHP and Apache then you need to point the webserver to the `/public` folder in the Laravel source code.
It seems you are using the root Laravel source code now, then next time go to this url `http://localhost/laravel/public/login`